# MYSQL / Select Query by 2-column relation

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I just only want to select those IDs whose status is equivalent to 2. And if the same ID has also a value grater than 2 then all the occurrences of this ID should be skipped.

Like the example below:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>status</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My expected result is "7".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need

```
select x.id from mytable x where status=2 and NOT EXISTS(Select y.id from mytable y where status > 2 and x.id = y.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a list of all ID's whose maximum status is 2. Its result will be "7":

```
SELECT ID FROM myTable
GROUP BY ID
HAVING MAX(Status) = 2
```

Comment: Shahrukh - could you post your query? The one in my answer returns only one column, and your comment above says you got back two columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id 
from table t1
inner join (select id, count(*) cnt from table group by id) t2 on
  t2.id = t1.id
  and t2.cnt = 1
where status = 2
```